# How can I detect what game a User is playing on discord using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I currently have this code

```
@bot.command()
async def user_activity(ctx, user_id):
    try:
        user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
        for activity in user.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
                await ctx.send(f"{user.name} spielt {activity.name}")
                return
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} hat keine Spielaktivität.")
    except discord.NotFound:
        await ctx.send("Benutzer nicht gefunden.")
```

This code will just throw me the error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'activities'

Ive tried another code like this

```
@bot.command()
async def user_activity(ctx, user_id):
    try:
        member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(user_id)
        for activity in member.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, discord.Game):
                await ctx.send(f"{member.name} spielt {activity.name}")
                return
        await ctx.send(f"{member.name} hat keine Spielaktivität.")
    except discord.NotFound:
        await ctx.send("Benutzer nicht gefunden.")
```

But this will just say that I am not playing anything even tho I am.

I tried getting the bot to say what game the user is playing but either I get an error or it says that Person is playing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why fetching a member from the guild doesn't correctly find the member's activities, but I found a pretty simple workaround.
First of all, instead of taking the user id as a parameter, take a Member object.

```
async def user_activity(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```

This removes the need to fetch a user or member. For some reason the member passed into the parameter correctly holds the activities of the member. After testing your code, I got it to work correctly as follows:

```
@bot.command()
async def activity(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    try:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if activity.type == discord.ActivityType.playing:
                await ctx.send(f"{user.name} is playing {activity.name}")
                return
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} is not playing anything.")
    except discord.NotFound:
        await ctx.send("User not found.")
```

Also, make sure you have your intents set correctly, for example something like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

If you have any questions just let me know. Have a great day!